# How to access the dom elements of other html from current html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

Suppose the current page is some1.html, and there is a second page, some2.html.  How can I access DOM elements in "some2.html" from some1.html using JavaScript?

Comment: Did you open it via `window.open` or something?

Comment: In short, you don't. AFAIK every single modern browser would class that as a XSS and block any attempt to manipulate DOM elements on another window. However, it is possible that if the window was opened with `window.open`, and was on the same domain it might be allowed.

Comment: If you check out my answer now, you'll find an extra part where I further explain how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

The way you could do this is by using AJAX:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    var $doc = $(data);
});
```

You can use that to get the contents from an url, and do something with it.

In response to your edit: You can then access the DOM elements by just doing `$doc.find('selector')` instead of the usual jQuery `$('selector')`.

You can also make it a bit easier by doing:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    var $doc = $(data);
    var $d = $doc.find;
});
```

in which case you can just use the syntax `$d('selector')`.

---

The way you'd do this without jQuery installed would be:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function(e) {  
    var doc = e.target.responseXML;
}
```

and then you can access DOM elements via `doc.getElementById('id')` just like you'd normally select elements, but using `doc` instead of `document`.

Note: for these functions, the `$doc`, `$d` and `doc` variables are only accessible within the callback function (so they're only accessible within the function where they're defined).

Comment: Your non-jQuery example is not browser agnostic.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. What part of it wouldn't work then?

Comment: I believe on IE <= 6, `XMLHttpRequest` is not defined (I know, IE compatibility is a pain). It's not a huge deal. I upvoted your answer, but thought that it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Only [0.3% of internet users](http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php) still uses it, so I've decided to just ignore the browser that [lacks support](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) for so many incredibly simple things, such as CSS `.classname.classname` or `E > F` or `E + F` selectors. Since almost every site would probably use some of those basic selectors, I'm sure there are **very** few sites left that actually supports IE6. Can't hurt to not be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Your code shows that the new page is being loaded in the same window.

The JavaScript environment for page1 will disappear before the environment for page2 is created. Since they don't exist at the same time, you can't access the DOM of one from the other.

What you could do is store some data in localstorage or a cookie, and have code you place in page2 look for that data and run JS based on what it says.

Answer (score -2):

You could experiment a bit with Ajaxh, because, as Quentin said, changing `window.location.href` will load the chaned file. or use an iframe like this:

```
var frame= document.createElement('iframe');
frame.setAttribute('src', 'some2.html');
frame.setAttribute('name', 'some2');
frame.appendTo(body);
var some2 = document.frames['name'];
//now you can acces to some2 with getElementById,...
```